# Create Gantt View for External Lists Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, gantt-view

I created External List in SharePoint 2010. I want to create a Gantt View for this external list now. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a Gantt view to work you have to have at least a description, a start date and an end date.  For an external list, try adding Start and End date columns and create a new view.  Select Gantt from the new view options.